# How can serve a (python based) tornado webserver a zip file?

Tags: python, zip, tornado

I'm using a python based tornado webserver.
I would like to download a zip file at the client side from the webserver.

I can serve a simple .csv file but not a .zip file.

---

This is how I make downloadable a .csv file:

[image: enter image descriptio![enter image description here]

...

[image]

---

This is how I tried to serve a .zip file:
[image]

When I try to download the file, I get this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3, binary files like zip files must be opened in binary mode. Use "rb" instead of "r" as the second argument to `open()`.